# How kernel building is a memory intensive application?

Tags: linux, kernel, benchmark

What makes benchmarks like `kernel-build`, `pbzip`, `pfscan` memory-intensive applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compilation is actually rather read/write intensive than just consuming large amounts of memory so it is a good measurement for IO-speeds of your memory.
But the bottleneck is probably either your disk or your CPU so there is better RAM benchmarks